# Is there a solution for triangle-based crafting tree?

Tags: python, pygame

I programed a thing that takes pictures from `pic` and connect some of them by lines based on `crafting.txt` then you can move the pictures in the program.

However after I added some pictures and conect them I found out that there are some crossing points which I don't want to have here (picture see below). So is there a solution to make it non-crosing? (The lines could be bended if needed) There are not all the pictures yet, I first need to find a solution for this problem before I will continue.
[image: FCT]

Also [here is the whole code](https://github.com/Brambor/Factorio-Crafting-Tree) if you are intersted in it.

Comment: I'm not sure it's actually *possible* to rearrange that such that no lines cross.

Comment: That is what I am asking for. If there is a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is proven that such a drawing without intersections is possible if and only if it is impossible to get to K3,3 or K5 by removing the nodes or edges and by replacing "proxy nodes" (those connected to exactly two others) with an edge. (Kuratowski's theorem)

K3,3 is a graph where  you have two sets 3 nodes each and the pairs of nodes with one node from each set are connected (like that https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/4e/Graph_K3-3.svg).

K5 is a graph with 5 nodes with every node pair connected (a 5 element complete graph).

So no, it is provably impossible to do in this case as it is possible to bring it to K5. Remove a piece of steel and blackish thing in the center. Then replace nodes on the path from the left gear to the central circuit with a single edge. You now have a K5.